# Shaded 3D ellipsoid with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying to display a shaded 3D ellipsoid with axis labels with PGFplots. So far I achieved this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        axis equal,
        axis lines = center,
        y label style={at={(axis cs:0,2,0)},anchor=west},
        xlabel = {$\lambda_1,\ \vec{e}_1$},
        ylabel = {$\lambda_2,\ \vec{e}_2$},
        zlabel = {$\lambda_3,\ \vec{e}_3$},
        ticks=none,
    ]
    \addplot3[%
        shader=interp,
        opacity = 0.3,
        fill opacity=0.3,
        surf,
        colormap/blackwhite,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:180,
        y domain = 0:360,
    ]
    ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {0.5*cos(v)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Ugly ellipsoid]
This shading does not give a 3D impression, I would like to have somethin like this:
[image: Cool ellipsoid]

Is it possible to define a new 3d shading in this coordinate system? I could not find such a command in the pgfplot documentation. All predefined shadings are not suitable.
Glad for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `{}` in the gui to highlight blocks of code -- or indent them by 4 spaces

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, PGFplots does not do "realistic" (light-based) shading. Have you considered [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/)?

Answer (score 3):

I saw your post to [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/) earlier, so I already added an answer to your topic [Shaded ellipsoid with PGFplots](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=26575):

You could use point meta = u. And you could play with the colormap, as I did on the axis.

I added `colormap={}{ gray(0cm)=(0.8); gray(1cm)=(0);}` and `point meta = u to the plot`:

[image: Ellipsoid]

Answer (score 3):

Make circles, know points in circles, stretch and rotate with "scope"
Here my code:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1, xscale=1, opacity=0.5]
% second sphere
    \begin{scope}[rotate=45, xscale=3, yscale=2, shift={(2.3,-0.2)}]
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
      \shade[ball color=gray!10!] (0,0) coordinate(Hp) circle (1) ;

      \draw[] (O) circle (1);
      \draw[rotate=5] (O) ellipse (1cm and 0.66cm);
      \draw[rotate=90] (O) ellipse (1cm and 0.33cm);
      \draw[rotate=40] (O) ellipse (0.404cm and 0.135cm);
      \fill[black]  (O) circle (1pt);

      \coordinate(L1) at (1,0);
      \node[above ] at (L1) {$\lambda_1$};
      \draw[-latex] (O) -- (L1);

      \coordinate(L2) at (0,1);
      \node[left ] at (L2) {$\lambda_2$};
      \draw[-latex] (O) -- (L2);

      \coordinate(L3) at (0.3064,0.257);
      \node[right,yshift=2mm] at (L3) {$\lambda_3$};
      \draw[-latex] (O) -- (L3);

    \end{scope}

% axis
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Here the resulting figure:
[image]